# Bootstrap custom footer issue with CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've linked in the comments below to JSFiddler. You will be able to see that I've managed to get the mobile footer working fine but the CSS for devices bigger than mobile the CSS I want isn't working.

I've put a pull-left on the copyright text and a pull-right on the social icons but the pull right doesn't seem to be working, not sure why. Also I want the copyright text be centered vertically. I've tried to used vertical-align: middle; but it hasn't worked.

```
<footer>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 pull left">
                    <p class="copyright text-muted">Copyright &copy; Eat Sleep Kayak 2015</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 pull-right">
                    <ul class="list-inline">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                                    <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                                    <i class="fa fa-facebook fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                                </span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                                    <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                                    <i class="fa fa-twitter fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                                </span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                                    <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                                    <i class="fa fa-google fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                                </span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                                    <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                                    <i class="fa fa-youtube fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                                </span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>

@media (max-width:768px){
    footer {text-align: center; padding: 10px;}
}

footer {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  background-color: #eee;
  padding-top: 5px;
}
footer .list-inline {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
footer .copyright {
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Comment: what is that.. dont link your code like that.. it troubles everyone on same page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `pull-left` and `pull-right` are attached to the wrong elements!

Attach those classes to the p (`pull-left`) `<p class="copyright text-muted pull-left">` and `u` `<ul class="list-inline pull-right">` -element. Those are the elements you want to pull!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of vertical-align: middle try:

```
.example {
    margin-top: 50%;
    margin-bottom: 50%;
}
```

Comment: what about this? 

    margin-top: auto;
    margin-bottom: auto;

Comment: on your fiddler putting just margin-top: 50%; is working for me

Answer (score 0):

Hope it solved the issue :)

```
.soc-sect{
    margin-top: 0px;
}
```